# Issue with Python TigerGraph GSQL - EOF in multi-line string

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, tigergraph

New to coding, trying this piece of code in Colab notebook and getting this error. Multi-line string seems to be an issue for some reason and I can't figure it out. Please help

```
print(conn.gsql('''
CREATE QUERY accountActivity() FOR GRAPH AMLSim {
SumAccum<DOUBLE> @s_sumAmt, @r_sumAmt;
SumAccum<DOUBLE> @s_txCnt, @r_txCnt;
MinAccum<DOUBLE> @s_minAmt, @r_minAmt;
MaxAccum<DOUBLE> @s_maxAmt, @r_maxAmt;
AvgAccum @s_avgAmt, @r_avgAmt;
Seed = {Account.*};
acctSend = SELECT tgt FROM Seed:s -(Send_Transaction:e)-> Transaction:tgt
ACCUM s.@s_sumAmt += tgt.amount, s.@s_txCnt += 1, s.@s_minAmt += tgt.amount, s.@s_maxAmt += tgt.amount, s.@s_avgAmt += tgt.amount
POST-ACCUM s.current_balance = s.@s_sumAmt - s.init_balance, s.min_send_tx = s.@s_minAmt, s.max_send_tx = s.@s_maxAmt, s.avg_send_tx = s.@s_avgAmt, s.cnt_send_tx = s.@s_txCnt;
acctRecieve = SELECT tgt FROM Seed:s -(reverse_Recieve_Transaction:e)-> Transaction:tgt
ACCUM s.@r_sumAmt += tgt.amount, s.@r_txCnt += 1, s.@r_minAmt += tgt.amount, s.@r_maxAmt += tgt.amount, s.@r_avgAmt += tgt.amount
POST-ACCUM s.current_balance = s.@r_sumAmt + s.init_balance, s.min_recieve_tx = s.@r_minAmt, s.max_recieve_tx = s.@r_maxAmt, s.avg_recieve_tx = s.@r_avgAmt, s.cnt_recieve_tx = s.@r_txCnt;
PRINT "Features Have Been Calculated";
}
INSTALL QUERY accountActivity
''', options=[]))
```

**Error message -**

```
ERROR:root:An unexpected error occurred while tokenizing input
The following traceback may be corrupted or invalid
The error message is: ('EOF in multi-line string', (1, 0))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ExceptionCodeRet                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-ba8252ad858f> in <module>()
     16 }
     17 INSTALL QUERY accountActivity
---> 18 ''', options=[]))
```

Answer (score 1):

hey user16772647 your error code show ExceptionCodeRet but you didn't share the value , if you try to reproduce it , that will give you a number ( Ex : 212 , 213 ... ) .

The error codes are listed here : https://docs.tigergraph.com/faqs/error-codes

I assume the error can be one of these :

- Didn't use the graph : solution append this to the top of your conn.gsql `USE GRAPH AMLSim`
- The graph doesn't exist : Solution double check that in graph studio
- The Query is already Created or Installed : Check it by printing the schema `print(conn.gsql('ls'))`

Let me know if that helps :)